# jquery script for gathering info about an image

Tags: jquery, css

I just need a quick suggestion. I posted this question before but people misunderstood my intention. I'm having trouble knowing how to ask for what I want, so bear with me.

I'm trying to find a script that I can use for an image gallery, basically the user would have the option of adding image info (such as title, filename, or whatever) to a "wish list" or "favorites box" or "bookmark place."

For example, let's say they could right-click on a thumbnail, and have an option: "add this to wish list."

Another example: Picture a div box that is position:fixed and it says, "Drag images you want to review later into this box."

So they would build a collection of "favorite images", it doesn't really matter how.

You get what I'm trying to figure out? Just give me some hints of things I could look into, thanks. (In the last thread I posted someone accused me of trying to get others to write scripts on my behalf. I'm obviously not asking for this.) Thank you. :)

Comment: Why don't you pick one of those options, let's say the drag'n'drop one, and _try_ to implement it. Then if you get stuck post a question that asks about a specific problem with what you've done.

Comment: I don't understand the attitude, have I done something wrong? There seems to be a quick judgment that I'm just this lazy 'help vampire' or whatever it is. Is it not cool to come here and post a general question asking for suggestions like this? I don't understand what the problem is. This is twice now -- same question -- and right away I'm 'in trouble' for doing something wrong. Jesus.

Comment: you can start with one of the jQuery UI demos that does most of what you want already  http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager. Overall your type of question is not a match for this site

Comment: jqueryui.com/droppable, BAM. Perfect, thanks man. And as for the type of question not being a good match for this forum, what forum would you suggest where I can go, "Guys, I'm looking for something that does XYZ, can you point me in the right direction?" without actually getting banned (yes I've been banned from here for this type of question)? I love this forum but man, people are too quick to paranoia-project 'help vamp' onto an innocent questioner.

Comment: Attitude? I didn't vote to close or anything, and I think banning someone should be a last resort, but if, as per your last comment, you've actually been banned for this type of question that's more than a hint that it's probably best not to ask this type of question. As it stands, this question is very open-ended - you had not even narrowed down to a particular desired behaviour - so that kind of falls within the ["don't ask" category in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). If you'd tried "jquery drag and drop image" in Google you'd have found some good suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understood, you are looking for an online picture gallery. You will need server-side development as you are about to have functionalities that require some decisions to be made at server-side. My suggestion to you is that you search the web for terms such as **ASP.NET Online Photo Gallery** or **PHP Online Photo Gallery**. You can find templates for galleries in **CMSs (Content Management Systems)** like **Umbraco** but you have to do some developments to have what you want because they don't have those wish lists or favorites lists.

Tell me if I could be of any more help,
Shakib